# itext-rtf Table within a Cell

Tags: java, itext, rtf

I'm using itext-rtf 2.1.7 to generate an RTF document.

The parameter **table** below for the method **writeSectionHeaderTableInACell()** will have two columns.

For each column, I need to insert a new inner Table, with two columns as well. This inner table will have the first column as left-aligned, and the second as right-aligned.

However, the code below causes a corrupted Table in the generated RTF document. The two inner Tables which supposed to be both on a single row, they appear as one row for each inner Table.

Anyone, has any idea why it seems we cannot add an inner Table within a Cell for RTF document? Thanks.

```
private static void writeSectionHeaderTableInACell(PdfPTable table) {
  PdfPTable sectionTable1 = new PdfPTable(2);
  Phrase phrase1 = new Phrase("? 1 ?", FontFactory.getFont("MS Mincho", 10, Font.NORMAL));
  Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(phrase1);
  p1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
  PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(p1);
  sectionTable1.addCell(cell1);
  Phrase phrase2 = new Phrase("2 Chi", FontFactory.getFont("MS Mincho", 10, Font.NORMAL));
  Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph(phrase2);
  p2.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
  PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(p2);
  sectionTable1.addCell(cell2);
  table.addCell(new PdfPCell(sectionTable1));

  PdfPTable sectionTable2 = new PdfPTable(2);
  Phrase phrase3 = new Phrase("Section 1", FontFactory.getFont("Times New Roman", 10, Font.NORMAL));
  Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph(phrase3);
  p3.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
  PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(p3);
  sectionTable2.addCell(cell3);
  Phrase phrase4 = new Phrase("2 Eng", FontFactory.getFont("Times New Roman", 10, Font.NORMAL));
  Paragraph p4 = new Paragraph(phrase4);
  p4.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
  PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(p4);
  sectionTable2.addCell(cell4);
  table.addCell(new PdfPCell(sectionTable2));
}
```

Comment: To generate the RTF document, of course, we have to use the **RtfWriter2** class. Using that class, the table on the generated RTF document is corrupted. When using the same method **writeSectionHeaderTableInACell()**, but using a different writer, the **PdfWriter** class, it can generate a PDF document properly, with the desired output of a Table within a Cell.

Comment: See my comment on your previous question.